# What do you call a single entry of a webcomic?

Tags: terminology

For instance, say I'm talking about XKCD number [936](https://xkcd.com/936/). Would this be "episode 936" or "issue 936" or "volume 936" or what is the correct term for this?

Comment: That is a matter of personal choice. See what each artist calls them. Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: *Issue* and *volume* sound like significantly larger pieces of work than a single page of cartoons. Out of the three, *episode* sounds most appropriate in this context.

Comment: Okay, I guess I was hoping there was one particular term that was appropriate rather than just a personal choice.

Comment: It is interesting to note the related word [webisode](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/webisode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth noting that the [XKCD forum](http://forums.xkcd.com/) refers to a particular XKCD entry as a **comic**. Most readers of XKCD would probably just refer to individual entries as "XKCD 936" though.

But the longer answer is going to depend on a few things, and there isn't a single standard that everybody obeys. That being said, we can define a few words:

[**Strip:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_strip) This can either refer to a series in general, or a particular entry of that series. This is usually how webcomics or newspaper strips are referred to.

- "Marmaduke is my favorite comic strip."
- "Tuesday's Marmaduke strip was very funny."

**[Comic book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book):** This can refer to a series in general, or a particular entry in that series. This is usually how print comics are referred to.

- "Spider-Man is my favorite comic book."
- "Give me back my comic book!"

**Issue:** This usually refers to the comic book entries that come out every month. They're usually like a magazine (so not like a paperback  or hardback book), and contain about 30 pages that link together to tell a story. They are usually numbered, so you can refer to "issue 100" for example.

- "In issue 4 of Squirrel Girl, she faces Galactus!"

**Volume:** This is a collection of single issues, organized into a single book. Also called a [Trade paperback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_paperback_(comics)). This usually collects a single "arc" (storyline) into one book. Some volumes can be larger, maybe collecting entire series into a single book.

- "Volume 2 of The Walking Dead collects issues 6-12."
- "I don't like waiting a month between issues, so I wait for the trade paperback to come out instead."

The only time you'll hear somebody refer to comics as **episodes** are when they're trying to invoke TV, which works in similar ways: individual issues are like individual episodes, arcs are like seasons, and volumes are like box set DVD releases. I actually like calling single issues of comics episodes, but it might come off as "incorrect" depending on how snooty the people you're talking to are.